# Can a single section break surround multiple section breaks (e.g S1, S2, S3, S1)? [Word 2010]

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

Our document templates require a specific layout. What I want is a document to be sectioned as such:

- Section 1
- Section 2
- Section 3
- Section 1

The purpose is to have a standard reference endnotes at the end of the document (second section 1) with separate sections with endnotes in the middle. Using footnotes and endnotes is not always possible as the footnote bottom of the page formatting disrupts the template, Footnotes will work in some cases, but not all.

The greatest issue is that I need to present the template in a low-tech manner. I cannot have VBA codes, macros or use a citation manager as that will be too complex for end users.

I have been searching for a while and playing with settings, but I do not think Word will allow this, but I would love to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 0):

### No

Section breaks in Microsoft Word are atomic markers, not block elements like `<DIV>` in HTML.

### However ...

You appear to be asking an XY question, i.e. you want to accomplish X, you think Y is the solution, and so you are asking about Y. Wrong thing to do. You actually came close to explaining how your document should look but didn't quite manage to explain your X. Try editing your question and explaining how exactly you want the document to look like.